# If the trace of the product of two matrices is zero,is the product of the matrices zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, positive-semidefinite

Does $\:\operatorname{ Tr}(XY) = 0 \Rightarrow XY=O $, for all $X,Y \succeq O$ ?

Comment: Do you mean that $X$ and $Y$ are nonnegative matrices, or positive semi-definite? Furthermore, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Let $A$ and $B$ be the positive semi-definite square roots of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, i.e. $X = A^2$ and $Y = B^2$ where $A,B \succeq O$. Try to prove $\text{tr}(XY) = \|AB\|_F^2$ (the cyclic property of the trace might help). After doing this, if $\text{tr}(XY) = 0$, what can you say about $AB$, and consequently $XY$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $X = \sum_{i}x_ix_i^*$ and $Y = \sum_{j}y_jy_j^*$, then
$$
XY = \sum_{i,j} (x_i^*y_j)x_iy_j^*, \quad \operatorname{tr}(XY) = \sum_{i,j} |x_i^*y_j|^2.
$$